# Mnemonic for always overriding equals when you override hashCode?

Tags: java

We java developers always know that you should [always override equals() when you override hashCode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java), but I consistently have trouble remembering this rule.

What is a clever mnemonic to help Java developers remember this?

Comment: Forget mnemonics, learn how hash tables work ;-)

Comment: Aging Onions Exercise When You Obtain Hiccups

Comment: OEOH ==> Override Equals; Override Hashcode  ==> Orange Equestrians Operate Helicopters

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: I could've sworn there was a song where part of the chorus is "Oh Ee Oh" .  That maps well to "O E OH"

Comment: "...these questions aren’t educational in any way, because there’s no way to learn about the process of discovery. A particular community member, by virtue of their experience in the field, just happens to be able to take the limited information you remembered and fill in enough of the blanks to guess the correct answer... guessing game questions do not meet our goal of making the Internet better." (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game)

Comment: @Brian: [Winkies on parade](https://youtu.be/nx8-J66yawM?t=29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is interesting that no one has pinpointed that OP' assumption that one has to override `equals()` when `hashCode()` is overridden is completely false. Though the opposite holds true - when `equals()` is overridden you have to override `hashCode()` as well. The mnemonic is very easy, just use the first letter of each method.  **e**quals() is before **h**ashCode() in the English alphabet so - *"if e then h"*.

Comment: It was a trick question! :-P

Answer (score 8):

Using [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) or [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) as part of your build process?

Or set your IDE to warn about this? At least [Eclipse can be configured for that since Eclipse 3.5](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=38751), and NetBeans.

Note that your IDEs can also probably generate them for you (more or less correctly).

Comment: Also NetBeans can be configured for this.

Comment: @UwePlonus: I'd assume all major IDEs can, but as I wasn't sure I didn't want to state it outright. Thanks for verifying.

Comment: Most tech interviews wont' let you run findbugs ;) (updated question tags appropriately)

Comment: @noahz: true, I probably won't let you run FindBugs during the interview. But I wouldn't mind that you mention using or running it.